# Magento 2 - How to call sales_order_save_after Observer manually for testing?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, sales-order, sales

i have a working Observer on the event sales_order_save_after.
The Observer looks like this:

```
namespace Company\ExportOrder\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface; 



class Observer implements ObserverInterface { 

    protected $connector; public function __construct() { 
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) { 
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $orderId = $order->getId();
        $customerId = $order->getCustomerId();

        // do something
    }
}
```

How am i able to call this Observer manually for testing? I don´t really want to create orders again and again. Idea is something like this:

```
$model = $objectManager->create('\Company\ExportOrder\Observer\Observer');
$model->execute();
```

But the execute-Function expects the Observer Model, and how can i set the order id manually for testing the function?

Answer (score 1):

Simply create one test order and try to change status of the same order everytime. This will trigger the event `sales_order_save_after`

```
$orderId = 1;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order') ->load($orderId);
$orderState = "holded";
$order->setState($orderState)->setStatus("holded");
$order->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following way:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
/** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load(1884);
$eventManager = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface');
$eventManager->dispatch('sales_order_save_after', ['order' => $order]);
```